# Serving protected images in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next.js along with next-auth for OAuth and want to serve images that would be accessible only to authenticated users. Images are stored on the same machine as Next.js app, e.g. in `assets/images` directory. How would I serve them from there? Do I need to create an api endpoint inside of `api` directory and fetch them when rendering a protected page?

Comment: You don't need to create an additional API. Just protect your page, it is just enough... Your API is already safe in next.

Comment: The answer would be the same as in any Node.js server, nothing Next.js specific here. Yes, you need an endpoint that checks auth and serve your image depending on the requested URL.
Other approach would be to put them in a `public` folder, and instead focus on securing your server using a proxy. As a JS dev I know this approach is less attractive because it means devops work, yet it's cleaner and let you keep your code simple.